# AWS PHP SDK using a FORM to upload to an S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following form

```
<form id="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" apaction="uptos3.php">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file"></input>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="uploadtoS3">Upload to S3</button>

</form>
```

And my code, on the same page as the form, to load an S3 Object to a S3 Bucket.

```
try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'mybucketS3/folderS3/',
        'Key'    => $_FILES['file']['name'],
        'Body'   => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ]);

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . PHP_EOL;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

How could I make, that when a user submits the file, that file is directly stored onto S3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post the file to PHP code that then uses S3 PHP API to place the file into a bucket. Here is the PHP code example that shows you how to upload an object into a bucket.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/php/example_code/s3/PutObject.php